# Remove user session indicator in Unity?

Tags: unity, indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don’t display user name in panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87649/dont-display-user-name-in-panel)

Is there any possibility to remove my user session applet from the top pane of Unity in Ubuntu 11.10? I mean that with my name. It only wastes space. However, when I tried to uninstall session-indicator (with session-applet), the applet disappeared, but the very right button (that to shut down laptop or access system settings) was also gone.

How can I remove only the session applet (is it the right name of it?) - that applet displaying my name?