# How can I remove username from panel in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, uninstall, panel, username

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using **12.10** or an earlier version?  Do you mean at the top right (after logged in)? or, at login page?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/87649/dont-display-user-name-in-panel?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

The **User Menu** applet from the top panel was removed in **12.10**, therefore by default, it **does not** display the logged in user’s name around the right-edge (in the system tray area) of the top panel.

Instead, the "**cog wheel**" menu at the top right corner, displays a list of users to quickly switch sessions.

[image]

Thus, you don't need to do anything to remove the logged in user's name from the top panel.

Now, if you've tweaked your installation and used **Dconf Editor** to show your user name on the top panel, just navigate to **apps → indicator-session** and uncheck "**show-real-name-on-panel**".

From the terminal, you can show the logged in user's name by running command below:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true
```

and this to remove the user name:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel false
```

---

**Sources**:

http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/10/make-ubuntu-12-10-display-user-name-on-top-panel-tip/
http://handytutorial.com/ubuntu-12-10-show-username-on-unity-panel/