# How can I remove indicator-session with 12.10

Tags: unity, indicator, dconf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don’t display user name in panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87649/dont-display-user-name-in-panel)

I would like to get rid of the `indicator-session` in Ubuntu 12.10.

There is nothing in `dconf` editor to remove this icon on the top right.

Does anyone have a clue?